# Что работает быстрее? Ввод и вывод с консоли или с файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Вводятся множество списков программа удаляет первое число списка и удаляет все числа в этом списке если встречается `1`.

Потом она их сортирует.

```
h = {}
i = 0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    s = input()[2:]
    s = s.split()
    if '1' in s:
        s = s[:s.index('1') + 1]
    h[i] = [float(item) for item in s]
    s = []
    print(h[i])
    i += 1

sorted_list = sorted(h.items(), key=lambda x: (len(x[1]), x[1]))
print(' '.join(str(i + 1) for i, _ in sorted_list))
```

`ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);` - такая строка в C++ ускоряет ввод и вывод в C++

Есть аналог в Питоне?

Пример в ввода:

```
20 # количество списков
5 3 4 4 2 3 3 #5 количество элементов в этом списке -1
5 2 3 4 3 2 3
6 3 3 3 2 2 4 4
6 2 2 3 3 2 2 3
3 2 2 2 2
4 4 4 2 3 3
4 3 3 3 2 3
2 3 2 3
4 4 2 2 2 3
2 3 4 4
3 3 4 4 4
5 4 2 4 2 2 4
3 2 3 2 4
5 3 2 2 4 2 3
2 3 2 2
5 2 4 2 2 2 2
6 2 4 3 4 4 2 2
4 2 4 3 4 4
6 2 2 4 4 2 4 2
6 4 2 2 4 4 3 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от объемов вводимого и выводимого. При небольших, быстрее консоль, так как открытие файла операция не быстрая. Но чем больше вывод (ввода, за его малости это не касается вообще), тем больше выгода от файла, так как консоль потребляет ресурсы на получение данных и скролинг постоянно, а не разово. И в какой-то момент он становится выгоднее.

Но все это имеет смысл на тысячах строк вывода. Предположу, что при ваших задачах, оба способа одинаково быстры — меньше секунды на ввод/вывод. Если же ошибаюсь, то только вы сами сможете определить оптимум, самостоятельно проведя тесты.

UPD: А вообще, преждевременная оптимизация — зло. Приступайте к ней, только если скорость работы перестанет устраивать. Причем начинайте с профилировщика, потому что тормоз может оказаться в любом месте, и IO на его фоне просто незаметен.

Comment: Так консоль имеет ограниченный размер информации, которую может отображать => по идее, производительность не должна снижаться.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Возможно консоли бывают разные, что тем более исключает возможность ответа со стороны. В виндовую, только что, вылил командой type мегабайтный текстовый файл.

Comment: у меня до 50000 тысяч списков входят программу где будет быстрее?

Comment: @СергейАлександров Это сможете определить только вы сами. Слишком все индивидуально. Поставьте альтернативную консоль `pip install ipython`, выделите тестируемый фрагмент в отдельную функцию и запустите `%timeit test_func()`. Но возможно, важнее окажутся организационные удобства. При таких объемах, файл удобнее. А если иногда нужно получать из консоли, реализуйте оба варианта ввод-вывода. Проверяйте параметр запуска, если он файл, работаем  с файлом, если нет — значит это данные и читаем с консоли. Если же логика еще более сложная — argparse для разбора аргументов командной строки.